# Variables in setTimeout function don't work continuously

Tags: javascript, function, variables, settimeout

my Problem is, that my loop with a SetTimeout function does work but I need it to subtract one variable from another every 50ms but it only works once. Here is my code:

```
<label for="customRange1">Weighting <output id="amount1" name="amount1" for="rangeInput1">100</output>%</label>
                        <input type="range" id="customRange1" name="rangeInput1" class="custom-range" min="0" max="100" value="100"
                               oninput="this.form.amount1.value=this.value">
<p id="display"></p>
```

```
 function input1(ev) {
     function1();
    var outputvalue1 = document.getElementById('amount1').value;
}
document.getElementById('customRange1').addEventListener('input', input1);



var weightingall = 100;
function function1(){
     var weighting1 = outputvalue1;
     var inputmax = weightingall - weighting1;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = test5;
    setTimeout(function1, 50);
}

function1();
```

Comment: what is `test5` and what is `outputvalue1`, and why is  `inputmax` never *read*? There seems a lot missing in your script...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to do an interval, you should not use `setTimeout`, but rather `setInterval`.

The `setInterval` function works in the same way as the `setTimeout`, it takes a callback and an amount of milliseconds. It also return an interval object that can be used to stop the interval when passing it to the `clearInterval` function.

Your code was not working because you were never changing the value of `weightingall`. So you would end up with the same amount each time.

Here I've produce a working prototype of your code. Please note that i've removed a few things in order to make it work properly. You can't simply copy and paste this into your code expecting every thing to works.

```js
var weightingall = 100;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  var weighting1 = 10;
  // we remove 10 each time.
  weightingall = weightingall - weighting1;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = weightingall;
  // if the weightingall variable comes down to 0, we clear the interval.
  if(weightingall <= 0 ){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Please note that i've used Arrow function and `let` here for scoping issue.
 [You should always use `let`/`const` rather than `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: In most cases `setTimeout` is safer than `setInterval` - even when you want intervals - but it depends on the use case.

Comment: @Ben that's true. I think it is safe in this case, but we don't know a lot about OP's context so I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but when I am using the code it says NaN in the text box... I edited my post to post more code that I am using sorry I forgot to do that when I was creating my post

Comment: @fafa_60_ from what i can get from the code you added,  you can't access the variable `outputvalue1`, since it is define in the `input1` function, using `var`. you should read the link i've provided about variable scoping. This might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help?

```js
let counter = 100;

function countdown() {
    console.log(counter--)        
    if(counter >= 0) { setTimeout(countdown, 50) }
}
countdown()
```